# Plotting inline in R on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: r, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook

In testing R in Jupyter Notebook, I am trying to create a plot inline, similar to %matplotlib inline in a jupyter python instance.

Within jupyter, I open an R instance and run the following:

```
install.packages('ggvis', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
library(ggvis)
iris %>% ggvis(~Sepal.Length, ~Sepal.Width, fill = ~Species) %>% layer_points()
```

When running this command, it tries to open up an html file using Sublime Text editor.

Does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only is an issue with ggvis. I used ggplot and everything works fine.